# Create new Hooks in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-hooks

I'm not looking about how to **implement** an existing hook, but rather to create a new *type* of hook. Let's say the hook `hook_node_load()` exists. I want to create something like `hook_node_preload()`, that fires before the node is loaded.

I've searched and can't seem to find out where in the Drupal code hooks are being fired. I assume it's something like `module_invoke_all()` or something like that? But I'm not sure where it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal hooks are fired all over the place, throughout all of the Drupal process. There isn't one place that calls all of the hooks.

Below is a list of some of the functions from the Drupal core that create hooks:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/calls/module_invoke_all/7

In the case of `hook_node_load()`, it is called from the entity.inc file located at **includes/entity.inc**, at line 334.

```
foreach (module_implements($this->entityInfo['load hook']) as $module) {
  call_user_func_array($module . '_' . $this->entityInfo['load hook'], $args);
}
```